# Providing extra security for banking applications

Tags: applications, security

Device : Moto X Play (Rooted, Android 6.0.1)

I use my mobile for everything and rarely use a PC, including banking applications, which work fine with root.

- I have [XPrivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) recently installed but not configured yet for all apps
- [Adguard](https://m.adguard.com/en/welcome.html) installed, which maybe offers some protection of VPN ???( I don't want to use third party VPN apps, not sure if I can trust them)
- Tor is painfully slow though internet speeds are good

**What is a good way enhancing security for banking ?** - I mostly use banking apps and at times browser when I need functionalities that apps don't offer

( I have a vague notion that creating a guest user and having only banking apps run there with XPrivacy killing all but essential permissions could help but I am not sure)

**Edit:** Please avoid solutions involving OS upgrade to reduce vulnerabilities, physical security of device, encryption, using string passwords, changing them regularly etc

Comment: Can Knox be installed on other phones than Samsungs? That'd be good I assume.

Comment: @SarpSTA: There were noise around that possibility but AFAIK, it is no